# Converting integer to bits: TypeError: string indices must be integers - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, bit

I'm trying to run this program that counts the ones in the bit representation of `int`s. Here is the code:

```
def count_bits(n):
    return bin(n).replace("0b", "")
            
bits = count_bits(3)
for i in bits:
    if bits[i] == 1:
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter = counter
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
    if bits[i] == 1:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Try `if bits[int(i)] == 1:`

Comment: Type of `bits[i]` is integer, try converting it, or stringify `== '1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over `bits`, which is a string, so your `i` assumes the value of the characters in that string. You need to either convert all the characters to integers first, or find a better way to iterate over the bits.

Simple solution:

```
def count_bits(n):
    return list(map(int, bin(n).replace("0b", "")))
```

Or you can use `bits[int(i)]`.

---

However, a better and more pythonic solution would be to do this mathematically using bitshifts and a generator:

```
def bits(n):
    while n:
        yield n & 1
        n >>= 1

counter = sum(bits(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you iterate over `bits`, which is a string, `i` will also be a string, and you compare it to 1, which is an `int`. You need to either do something like this

```
def count_bits(n):
    return bin(n).replace("0b", "");

bits = count_bits(3);
for i in range(len(bits)):
    if bits[i] == 1:
        counter += 1;
    else:
        counter = counter;
```

so `i` will be an `int` and you compere it to `int 1`, or something like this

```
def count_bits(n):
    return bin(n).replace("0b", "");
            
bits = count_bits(3);
for i in bits:
    if bits[i] == "1":
        counter += 1;
    else:
        counter = counter;
```

so `i` will be a `string`, like originally, but you compare it to a `string "1"`.